# Is it possible to use here 1 VF component for 2 VF pages?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a controller with 2 different methods: first takes the list of today's masters, and second - the list of tomorrow's masters. It's all the difference between my PDF pages: I made them as List Buttons that show 2 different lists.

How can I move the main logic to a VF component and share it between 2 VF pages? If it's possible.

```
<apex:page standardController="Tool__c" extensions="PDFController" recordSetVar="tools" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @page {size: A4 landscape;}
        .listText{font-size: 12px;}
    </style>
</head>
    <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="count"/>
    <!-- The difference between 2 pages is just in methods: in the controller I have getTodaysMasters and getTomorrowsMasters methods. -->
    <!-- How can I add the general logic to an VF component and share it between 2 VF pages? -->
    <apex:repeat value="{!todaysMasters}" var="master">
        <apex:variable value="{!count+1}" var="count"/>
        <body>
           <div style="{!IF(todaysMasters.size == count, '','page-break-after:always;')}">      
               <apex:pageBlock title="{!master.Name}">
                   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!master.Tools__r}" var="toolInTable" border="1px" width="100%" cellpadding="2">
                       <apex:column value="{!toolInTable.RecordType.Name}" styleClass="listText"/>
                       <apex:column value="{!toolInTable.Adres__c}" styleClass="listText"/>
                       <apex:column value="{!toolInTable.Color__c}" styleClass="listText"/>
                   </apex:pageBlockTable>
                   <br/>
                   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(!ISBLANK(master.Comment__c))}">
                       <apex:outputText value="{!master.Comment__c}"/><br/><br/>
                   </apex:outputPanel>
                   <apex:repeat value="{!master.Tools__r}" var="mastersComment">
                       <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(!ISBLANK(mastersComment.Comment__c))}">
                           <tr><td>{!mastersComment.Adres__c + ' - ' + mastersComment.Comment__c}</td></tr>
                       </apex:outputPanel>
                   </apex:repeat>
               </apex:pageBlock>
            </div>
        </body> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the common code in a custom component with an **attribute** to hold the list of masters. On each of the 2 visualforce pages call the custom component with different parameter, one with todaysMasters, and the other with tomorrowsMasters.

Check the following links:

[Create Custom Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_creating.htm)

[Add custom components to visualforce pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_using.htm)